# Issue related to autocomplete textbox in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have Windows Application which I have added a `Textbox` and set the `AutoCompleteSource` property...

```
            txt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            txt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
```

I have set collection data from the database..

However when user selects some text from dropdown from the `Textbox`.. and hits <kbd>tab</kbd> to move to some other textbox or control.. nothing happens.. I mean the <kbd>tab</kbd> key doesn't working and `Textbox` doesn't lose its `focus()`, why? and what is the solution?

Comment: Have you tried to user the Enter Key or mouse click, instead of TAB?

Comment: no. but what if user want to move to some other control using TAB ?

Comment: if you have a dropdown control visible and hit tab, i guess it should move to the next item in the dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

It should go to next control - unless you have specified some code in any of the textBox1`s events. I just checked wtih this code, and it work, it goes to next control by pressing Tab key:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] array = { "aaa", "abc", "acc", "aac", "acc", "bcc", "cbb", "bbb" };
        //upper line iy my custom array, you get it from database
        AutoCompleteStringCollection autoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        autoComplete.AddRange(array);
        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComplete;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //you can use this event to get some data:
        string item = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    }
}
```

If you have only this code related to textBox is has to work!